# php redirection

Tags: php, mysql

My php script is working on localhost but after uploading online it's showing a blank page.

php installed on localhost  version 5.2.6
php installed on production environment version 5.1.4

```
<?php 
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
require 'connect.php';
session_start();                        
php require 'function.php';    
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
session_name('smsapp');
session_start(); 
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$pass = substr(md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].microtime().rand(1,100000)),0,6);
$str = "INSERT INTO members(fname, name, pass, phone, email, regIP, dt, level)
        VALUES(
               '".$fname."',
               '".$name."',
               '".md5($pass)."',
               '".$phone."',
               '".$email."',
               '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',
                  1,
                  NOW()
    )" ;
mysql_query($str);

if(mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1 && 
  ($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']))
{
    echo "Password will be sent to you by sms.";
    $url = "http://sms.kohlihosting.com/sendsmsv2.asp?
            user=username&
            password=12345&
            sender=kohli&
            text=Your+password" . $pass . "&
            PhoneNumber=".$phone;

    $homepage = file_get_contents($url) ;   
}
else if(!($_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code']))
{
    echo "Please Input correct letters ";
}
else
{
    echo "Not registered";
}
?>
```

This is the code which is working on localhost but not online.

Comment: This code is very difficult to read the way you have it formatted in this post.

Comment: Also, where is your second <?php opening tag? It looks like you need one right after <body>. That wouldn't explain why it works on localhost though.

Comment: sorry ! my coding wa is too bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility might be, the php.ini in the server has show-warnings disabled. And you are unable to connect to the database for some reason and the warning/errors are not shown.

In your connect code, you could try having an `connect() or die('something')` statement. This way if it does fail to connect, you see an error message.

Even in this is not the case, you should see if warnings/error messages are generated and are not shown due to the settings in php.ini and you might need to change it temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your host does not allow url access (for security reasons) when you use `file_get_contents`

If you have privilege, you can turn on url access in php.ini:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```